# Node.js bug after importing readline

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js 18.16.0 x64 on Windows 10 Pro 22H2 x64, I just encountered a strange bug that prevents me from using Node.js after importing readline.

I needed a way to get user input using only built-in and absolutely not any library that needs to be installed.

Any code that requires readline will trigger the bug.

I copy-pasted code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73189492/16383578):

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

readline.question(`What's your name?`, name => {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
  readline.close();
});
```

I get this:

```
Welcome to Node.js v18.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
...   input: process.stdin,
...   output: process.stdout,
... });
undefined
>
>
rreeaaddlliinnee..qquueessttiioonn((``WWhhaatt''ss  yyoouurr  nnaammee??``,,  nnaammee  ==>>  {{
...
    ccoonnssoollee..lloogg((``HHii  $${{nnaammee}}!!``));;
...
    rreeaaddlliinnee..cclloossee(());;
...
}}));;
```

Then after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> node.exe immediately closes itself.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69272697/16383578)

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function readLineAsync(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(message, (answer) => {
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
} 

// Leverages Node.js' awesome async/await functionality
async function demoSynchronousPrompt() {
  var promptInput = await readLineAsync("Give me some input >");
  console.log("Won't be executed until promptInput is received", promptInput);
  rl.close();
}
```

```
Welcome to Node.js v18.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const readline = require('readline');
solve(answer);
undefined
>
> const rl = readline.createInterface({
...   input: process.stdin,
...   output: process.stdout
... });
undefined
>
>
ffuunnccttiioonn  rreeaaddLLiinneeAAssyynncc((mmeessssaaggee))  {{
...
    rreettuurrnn  nneeww  PPrroommiissee((((rreessoollvvee,,  rreejjeecctt))  ==>>  {{
...
        rrll..qquueessttiioonn((mmeessssaaggee,,  ((aannsswweerr))  ==>>  {{
...
            rree        }}));;
...
    }}));;
...
}}
undefined
>

>
////  LLeevveerraaggeess  NNooddee..jjss''  aawweessoommee  aassyynncc//aawwaaiitt  ffuunnccttiioonnaalliittyy
undefined
>
aassyynncc  ffuunnccttiioonn  ddeemmooSSyynncchhrroonnoouussPPrroommpptt(())  {{
...
    vvaarr  pprroommppttIInnppuutt  ==  aawwaaiitt  rreeaaddLLiinneeAAssyynncc((""GGiivvee  mmee  ssoommee  iinnppuutt  >>""));;
...
    ccoonnssoollee..lloogg((""WWoonn''tt  bbee  eexxeeccuutteedd  uunnttiill  pprroommppttIInnppuutt  iiss  rreecceeiivveedd"",,  pprroommppttIInnppuutt));;
...
    rrll..cclloossee(());;
...
}}
```

Same thing happens.

What is going on?

Comment: Don't simply type `node` then paste the code, put it in a file then do `node filename.js`

Comment: Your problem is that you are in the REPL, https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html Thats a interactive shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug. You ran this in the REPL, creating a stream from stdin to stdout, so anything you type into the REPL after that would be duplicated. Run it from a file.